# Yeoman generator not getting installed in VDI

Tags: installation, yeoman

Trying to install(with Admin privileges) the Yeoman using "npm install -g yo generator-office" in VDI for Office Word Add-in
All the proxies and registry are set properly for the VDI, still facing the issue with below error.

npm install -g yo generator-office
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to open
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see request/request#3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo-complete -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\completion\index.js
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js

```
yo@3.1.1 postinstall C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
yodoctor

Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ No .bowerrc file in home directory
√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
√ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
√ Node.js version
ErrorClass [RequestError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\got\index.js:73:21)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org',
host: 'registry.npmjs.org'
hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
method: 'GET',
path: '/yo'
}
× yo version
ErrorClass [RequestError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
at ClientRequest. 

(C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\got\index.js:73:21)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org',
host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
method: 'GET',
path: '/yo'
}


Found potential issues on your machine
generator-office@1.7.6
yo@3.1.1
updated 2 packages in 194.549s
```